# Why is the Newtonsoft Json serializer ignoring the [JsonIgnore] attribute?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Consider the following class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string ValueString { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonIgnore]
    public object Value { get; set; } = "";

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<System.Attribute> Attributes { get; } = new ();
}
```

When trying to serialize an instance of this object I am using the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime;
settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include | DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
settings.FloatFormatHandling = FloatFormatHandling.DefaultValue;
settings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Double;
settings.MaxDepth = null;
settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
settings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto;
settings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
settings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
settings.TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Full;
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, typeof(TestClass), settings);
```

Exception:

```
JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'AutoGenerateField' on 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The AutoGenerateField property has not been set.  Use the GetAutoGenerateField method to get the value.
```

This exception ONLY occurs when the `Attributes` property has entries even though it is marked with the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute.

So far I have only tried populating the list with the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute` class so this may happen with others.

The question is:

1. Why is the serializer ignoring its own `[JsonIgnore]` attribute?
2. What am I doing wrong, if anything, with the serializer settings (`JsonSerializerSettings`)?
3. Is there another `Json` attribute that the `Attributes` property should be annotated with that I am missing?

Comment: There is also a `JsonIgnoreAttribute` in the `System.Text.Json` namespace (ie .NET built in JSON library) and they are not interchangeable. Make sure your attribute is from the correct namespace (ie `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute`)

Comment: Doh! Simpson moment. Thank you.